# Reset the Datetime as index and remove none infront of it with Close to make them column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

|  | Close |
| --- | --- |
| Datetime | None |
| 2023-05-10 00:00:00 | 135.222000 |

in this dataframe the there is a none in the row where datetime is there, i want to remove that none with Close and make Datetime and Close as new columns makinng datetime as index, in python.

I want something like this,below

| Datetime | Close |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-10 00:00:00 | 135.222000 |
| 2023-05-10 00:05:00 | 135.240005 |

Comment: It's not 100% clear from your question what the format of your dataframe is. Can you please add the output of `df.head().to_dict()` to the question to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: df.reset_index()